# Running Directory Traversal Against POST Request Headers

Tags: web-application, embedded-system, directory-traversal, zap

I'm trying to run a directory traversal against the EdgeOS web server. I started the OWASP ZAP proxy with Firefox and tried to login with an incorrect username and password to look at the POST request. I am trying to modify this request to run a directory traversal. I would like to run this attack against as many parameters as I can. Such as the `Connection:`, `User-Agent:`, `Referer:` and `Cookie:`. I am quite new to ZAP so any help would be appreciated.

```
GET https://192.168.1.1/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Referer: https://192.168.1.1/
Cookie: PHPSESSID=959ecee6b57f4030bee01175453e9854; X-CSRF-TOKEN=08e15a2c705ff9a30a958e7b36669e83e738b607a7f5e349d347a0a6e674141c; ip_address_top_user_option=total_bytes; beaker.session.id=538f34654a4441f4bfa63548d6e1b8e8
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Host: 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Directory traversal is tested as part of the ZAP active scan. By default all active scan rules are run, but you can define a scan policy which specifies exactly which rules are run, in your case just the directory traversal one.
ZAP also has the concept of active scan 'input vectors' - the things ZAP will actually attack. By default the HTTP headers will not be included, so you will need to enable these.
Its not clear from you post if you want the scan to be authenticated or not, if you do then that will complicate things - I'd start with an unauthenticated scan first and make sure thats working well before looking at authentication.

Comment: I wanted to run a directory traversal against an authenticated API but instead chose the login page because I didn't want to complicate things. How do I include the HTTP headers in the attack?

Comment: Via Options / Active Scan Input Vectors : https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsOptionsAscaninput#http-headers